# Inserting above/below X lines in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm wondering ho to insert arbitrary number of lines below curent line wit "o" command. When i type for example 5o, first new line is inserted directly below, so i can write and when I hit esc then the line gets copied four times. Is there any way to directly insert 5 blank lines and after that start typing without the need of 5+o+esc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred way of doing things like this is to use the dot command.

`o<esc>` to create the initial blank line, then repeat the command with `.`.

The dot command can also take a count so `5.` will repeat the last command 5 times.

You may also want to have a look at [unimpaired.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) as it has the following mapping:

`]<Space> - Add [count] blank lines below the cursor.`

Since it is a mapping you can also provide a count. e.g. `5]<space>`

unimpaired.vim also has many other convenient mappings. e.g. `]a` for `:next` and `]b` for :bnext`

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any way which does not involve a mapping or function :

```
:noremap <leader>o o<ESC>
:noremap <leader>O O<ESC>
```

With this, you can type `5\o` to insert 5 blank lines.

Comment: Please, use `nore` before `map` where possible.